# React Native Fetch POST TypeError: Invalid character in header field name

Tags: javascript, java, react-native, fetch

I have some problems with fetch, specifically with POST method. I have a login feature to log on to the app, but when I typed the username and the password, the error showed like below. This project is like a migration/rewrite from Android Studio to React Native. Note: email, password, device_id, and fcm_token is encrypted from the app and send it to the server as encrypted string.

Also, I tested it on Postman too with encrypted string to the body, and it works. Any suggestion why it throws an error? Thanks.

[image: postman]

[image: error]

Here's the code in React Native to fetch Login API

LoginEmail.js

```
...
await fetch(ApiUrl.login, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: new Headers({
          "Accept": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Eventku-Api-Key": AppData.apiKey
        }),
        body:
          JSON.stringify( {
            "&email=": cipherEmail.toString(),
            "&password=": cipherPass.toString(),
            "&device_id=": cipherDevice.toString(),
            "&fcm_token=": cipherToken.toString()
          })
      }).then(response => response.text()).then(responseJson => {
...
```

And here's the Java code to Login

ApiServices.java

```
...
//login using email
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
Call<ResponUser> login(
   @Field("email") String email,
   @Field("password") String password,
   @Field("device_id") String device_id,
   @Field("fcm_token") String fcm_token
);
...
```

LoginActivity.java

```
...
apiServices.login(
   Strings.encryptData(edtEmail.getText().toString()),
   Strings.encryptData(edtPassword.getText().toString()),
   Strings.encryptData(imeiNumber),
   Strings.encryptData(fcm.getString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN),""))
).enqueue(new Callback<ResponUser>() {
...
```

Comment: Don't know about your headers (all the names look fine) but you definitely don't want to be using `JSON.stringify()` to post `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` formatted data

Comment: @Phil may I know why? If I change the body with something like `"&email=" + cipherEmail.toString() +` is it okay?

Comment: Why? Because `JSON.stringify` produces JSON but you aren't posting JSON. Do a search for how to best create an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string in react native. In the browser, I'd just use `URLSearchParams` but I don't know if that's available to you

Comment: @Phil https://gist.github.com/juskangkung/6f0dbabc24c70413d075ae2605d8a50d sending you a controller file used from my BE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This caused by a 400 error code in my BackEnd, changed it to 200 and it didn't show the "Invalid character in header field name" error. Maybe React Native only process 200 code instead of 400